# When selecting radio button, how can I test if another is already selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, radio-button

I have a table with groups of 2 radio buttons in each row - it is a yes/no choice for a series of questions.

Selecting YES increments a variable to keep track of the total YES answers.  Selecting NO does nothing unless YES is already selected, in which case it decrements the total.

I can increment YES easy peasy.  The problem is detecting the status of YES when selecting NO, because by selecting NO, YES is no longer selected before I can test.  Schrödinger's button?

How can I click NO and test the status of YES before it is changed?

```
<input type='radio'  id = 'q1Y' name='q1' value='1Y' onChange='countY(this.id);'>
<input type='radio'  id = 'q1N' name='q1' value='1N'  onChange='countN(this.id);'>

function countN(id){
q = id.slice(0, -1);
/////////////////
//
// The problem is here.  By the time the code reaches this point, Y is already unchecked
//
////////////////
if($('#'+q+'Y').prop('checked')===true){
    score--;
    $("#scoretotal").html(score);
}
```

}

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Do you really need a running total, or can you calculate the total after the user answers all of the questions?

Comment: Sure, but why is the code even relevant?   The question is clear.

Comment: Use the `change` event instead of the click event. If you click on the button that's already selected, the event listener won't called.

Comment: That's not quite right, if neither is checked initially.

Comment: @RobertHarvey hmmm...good point.  But that relies on someone completing all questions (i.e. perform action after last question selected) or submitting the form which I was hoping to avoid.

Comment: @Barmar I am already using onChange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what worked, I appreciate the comments and answers, they pointed me to a solution.

```
var score=0;
$('input[type=radio]').mousedown(function(){

   question = this.value.slice(0, -1) // which button group?
   YN = this.value.substr(this.value.length - 1); // Y or N?

  if(YN=="Y"){
     $('#q'+question+'Y').prop('checked', true);  // set the buttons
     $('#q'+question+'N').prop('checked', false);       
     score++;
     $("#scoretotal").html(score);
  }
  else{
      if($('#q'+question+'Y').prop('checked')){ 
      //This is the test that made the difference because the other button hadn't been unchecked yet
          score--;
          $("#scoretotal").html(score);
       }
       $('#q'+question+'Y').prop('checked', false); //set the buttons
       $('#q'+question+'N').prop('checked', true);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `onmousedown` instead of `onchange`. This runs before the values of the buttons are changed to reflect the result of clicking.

But instead of incrementing and decrementing running count, it's simpler to just count all the `YES` buttons to get the total.

```
function count() {
    var total = $(":radio[value$=Y]:checked").length;
    $("#scoretotal").html(total);
}
```

Comment: This is a nice solution, and I am still interested in the answer as to whether it is possible to check the status of the other button - out of curiosity now ;o)

Comment: Do it in an `onmousedown` handler, this will run before the values are changed.

Comment: Wheither it is possible or not is really irrelevant with this solution.  Rather than having conditional logic based on the previous state of another radio button, this solution has one pathway to the same end result.

Answer (score 1):

Just increment or decrement a counter upon each click of a button in a set. Make sure to check for <= 0 values.

```js
// Get both buttons into an Array
let yesNo = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".yesNo"));

let total = document.getElementById("total");

let yesses = 0;

// Loop the Array
yesNo.forEach(function(btn){
  // Set up event handler
  btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
    if(this.value === "Yes"){
      yesses++;
    } else {
      yesses = yesses - 1 <= 0 ? 0 : yesses - 1;
    }
    
    total.textContent = yesses;
  });
});
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="yesNo" value="Yes" class="yesNo"> Yes
<input type="radio" name="yesNo" value="No" class="yesNo"> No
<div id="total"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use an object to map values for the answers so you can keep track which answers were answered.
If both functions (countY and countN) have a similar functionality you could also reuse the code as following:

```
<input type='radio'  id = 'q1Y' name='q1' value='1Y' onChange='count(this.name, true);'/>
<input type='radio'  id = 'q1N' name='q1' value='1N'  onChange='count(this.name, false);'/>


var map = {};
function count(id, bool){
    map[id] = bool;
    let scoreTotal = Object.keys(map).filter(keyName => map[keyName]).length;
    // if you want to know how many NOs
    let negative = Object.keys(map).filter(keyName => map[keyName] === false).length;
    $("#scoretotal").html(scoreTotal);
}
```